# Vmware Fusion, how to remove suspend option completely

Tags: macos, vmware

I have good number of virtual XP and W7 machines on our domain, one thing always cause problems when multiple users are using the same machine.  There's always that one person whom put the vm session on suspend instead of shutdown.  I know to change under preferences, but somehow users change default back to suspend.  Is there a way to enforce shutdown only.  this is the case for Fusion 5, 6.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [Disabling the suspend feature for a virtual machine in VMware Fusion](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/microsite.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=2056501):

> **VMware Fusion**
>
> To disable the suspend feature for a virtual machine:
>
> 1. Shutdown the virtual machine.
> 2. Locate the virtual machine bundle. For more information, see [Locating the virtual machine bundle in VMware Fusion (1007599)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1007599).
> 3. Press Ctrl and click the virtual machine bundle, then click Show Package Contents.
> 4. Open the .vmx file for editing in a text editor. For more information, see [Editing the .vmx file for your VMware Fusion virtual machine (1014782)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1014782).
> 5. Add this line to the .vmx file:
>      *suspend.disabled = "TRUE"*
> 6. Save and close the .vmx file.
> 7. Restart the virtual machine.